# Por que consigo acessar uma estrutura sem ser pelo ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Quando declaro um ponteiro para `struct` posso acessar membros sem colocar o endereço de um `struct`, por que é possível? Por exemplo:

```
struct exemplo{
    int a ; 
};

int main()
{
    struct exemplo *p;

    p->a = 10 ;    
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida, você está colocando, o endereço é `p`. tem um erro neste código, ele funciona por coincidência, mas nada a ver com sua dúvida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O operador `->` é o acesso via ponteiro de um membro de uma estrutura. Ele é açúcar sintático para `(*p).a`, no exemplo mostrado.

O código tem falhas. Ele até funciona, mas talvez não faça o que espera. Falta declarar o tipo para a estrutura (o código fica mais limpo) e alocar memória para acomodá-la. O código correto seria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
   int a;
} Exemplo;

int main(void) {
    Exemplo *p = malloc(sizeof(Exemplo));
    p->a = 10;    
    printf("valor = %d", p->a);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SWX7Nf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zkfibwir-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Pointer.c).

Não fica melhor assim?

Se não quiser declarar a variável para a estrutura, é possível fazer também, mas aí terá que ser explícito para todo uso dela, [veja como](http://ideone.com/q7GGLK). Créditos ao carlosfigueira por ter comentado sobre isto.

Se realmente quiser colocar a estrutura no *stack* (não usar `malloc()`, então não use ponteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
   int a;
} Exemplo;

int main(void) {
    Exemplo p = { 10 };
    printf("valor = %d", p.a);
    Exemplo p2 = { .a = 10 }; //apenas uma variação
    printf("valor = %d\n", p2.a);
    Exemplo p3;
    p3.a = 10; //outra variação
    printf("valor = %d\n", p3.a);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SqoBQc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zkfibwir-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Pointer2.c).

É possível fazer inicialização com ponteiro também.

Comment: Só um detalhe: você não precisa necessariamente declarar o tipo pra estrutura. Sem o `Exemplo` acima, a estrutura já tem um tipo (`struct exemplo`), que você pode usar no malloc: `malloc(sizeof(struct exemplo))`.

Comment: @carlosfigueira sim, realmente é possível, vou adicionar isto. Eu até já tinha feito uma modificação porque acabei invertendo a intenção.